# Quarkus Unsatisfied dependency for type javax.ws.rs.sse.Sse and qualifiers [@Default]

Tags: cdi, server-sent-events, quarkus

I try to reproduce https://github.com/volkaert/events-sse-quarkus ; here is an extract :

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/api-1.0/trevents")
public class SseRealTimeService {
private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
private long id;

private Sse sse;
private SseBroadcaster sseBroadcaster;

public SseRealTimeService(@Context Sse sse,final @Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
    this.log.debug(">>>>>>>>>>>>setSse :) " + sse);
    this.log.debug(">>>>>>>>>>>>httpHeaders :) " + httpHeaders);
    this.sse = sse;
}
...
```

And I get :

```
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: 
Found 2 deployment problems: 
[1] Unsatisfied dependency for type javax.ws.rs.sse.Sse and qualifiers [@Default]
- java member: org.avm.business.rest.api.SseRealTimeService#<init>()
- declared on CLASS bean [types=[org.avm.business.rest.api.SseRealTimeService, java.lang.Object],        qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.avm.business.rest.api.SseRealTimeService]
[2] Unsatisfied dependency for type javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders and qualifiers [@Default]
- java member: org.avm.business.rest.api.SseRealTimeService#<init>()
- declared on CLASS bean [types=[org.avm.business.rest.api.SseRealTimeService, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.avm.business.rest.api.SseRealTimeService]
```

As far as I understood, it means it didn't find any class implementing Sse interface which could be injected.

My pom (extract dependencies node) :

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- TESTS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have seen this https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6515
but it says v1.5 solved it ; my quarkus version is 1.8.0 (`<quarkus.platform.version>1.8.0.Final</quarkus.platform.version>` in pom.xml).

I'm lost ... any idea ?